# Plotting the entries in the dataframe and fitting the results using polyfit

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have the following `Dataframe`

| A1 | A2 | A2 | B1 | B2 | B3 | C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.4 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.4 |
| 0.4 | 0.1 | 0.4 | 0.5 | 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 0.5 |
| 0.3 | 0.4 | 0.05 | 0.6 | 0.9 | 0.4 | 0.5 | 0.7 | 0.6 |

and a list

```
list_A = [10,20,30]
```

I need to plot graphs where x are values in `list_A` versus y values **as columns** that are in `Dataframe`. There should be 3 separate graphs as follows:list_A vs A1, A2, A3; list_A vs B1, B2, B3 and list_A vs C1, C2, C3.

From this, I wound then like to extract slopes for every line in the graph (list_A vs A1, A2, A3; list_A vs B1, B2, B3 and list_A vs C1, C2, C3) and get the output in the following format (using `np.polyfit`)

```
output = [[slope1, slope2, slope3],[slope1, slope2, slope3],[slope1, slope2, slope3]]
```

Any ideas?

I tried to first split the dataframe into 3 smaller groups corresponding to A, B and C entries using `np.array_split(Dataframe, 3)` but it did not work as I expected

Comment: Can you provide an example polyfit/plotting command for one of your rows? Which part of the process are you struggling with, calling the functions or looping over the dataframe? I don't understand exactly what data contributes to each entry of your output.

Comment: Hi @Steve, I expanded the explanation in the text - hope it makes more sense now